# Changes made to dynamically added elements reverting automatically

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I'm dynamically adding `li` elements to the page inside a `ul` via PHP.

```
<ul class="auto-suggest-list" id="theul"></ul>
```

Then using jquery, I created a custom keyboard navigation for the list (up and down).

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.auto-suggest-textbox', function(e) {
    if($(this).val() != ''){
        $('.auto-suggest-list').slideDown();

        if(e.which == 38){
            position--;
            $('.auto-suggest-list').css('background-color','#fff');
            $('.auto-suggest-list li:nth-child(' + position + ')').css('background-color','#ddd');
        }
        else if(e.which == 40){
            position++;
            $('.auto-suggest-list').css('background-color','#fff');
            $('.auto-suggest-list li:nth-child(' + position + ')').css('background-color','#ddd');
        }

    }
    else if($(this).val() == ''){
        $('.auto-suggest-list').slideUp();
    }
});
```

But the background color of the list item reverts to `#fff` after a second. There is no css for the background color property, and I also tried other functions such as `text()` on the list items and they all keep reverting!

Here's part of the PHP code providing the li-s

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query_run)){
echo '<li>';
echo '<input type="hidden" value="'.$row['reciever_id'].'" name="recipients[]" />';
echo '<span>'.get_user_field('first_name',$row['reciever_id']).' '.get_user_field('last_name',$row['reciever_id']).'</span>';
echo '</li>';
```

}

Comment: How are you dynamically adding li elements to the page? can you post that code?

Comment: How can you dynamically add elements using PHP? PHP runs on the server, dynamica changes have to happen on the client.

Comment: Can you possibly set up a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with your code demonstrating the issue, please?

Comment: Just an efficiency tip. Use jquery chaining. `$('.auto-suggest-list').css('background-color','#fff').find('li:nth-child(' + position + ')').css('background-color','#ddd');`

Comment: PHP code added. Is it something to do with input type hidden?

Comment: Let me start by saying *you should use **[`MySQLi`](http://cz1.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)** or **[`PDO`](http://cz1.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)** instead of **[`mysql_*`](http://cz1.php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php)** functions, which are deprecated and will be removed in the future versions of PHP. [More information about that available here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).* Now, assuming there is nothing like AJAX in your code and there is `<ul>` before your PHP loop and `</ul>` after it, your PHP seems fine. But can you also post here the output from PHP?

Comment: And no, [as you can see here](http://jsfiddle.net/g3Fkb/2), `<input type='hidden'>` shouldn't cause any issue at all.

Comment: Here's the PHP output (1 li) :: <li><input type="hidden" value="1" name="recipients[]"><span>Name</span></li>

Comment: While navigating, the <li> shows the additional style attribute with background-color set to the value I'm specifying in jQuery, momentarily; and the other <li>s automatically get the same attribute with bg-color set to (255, 255, 255, 1)! Then in a second, the attribute just disappears from all the generated <li>s

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing both instances of:

```
$('.auto-suggest-list').css('background-color','#fff');
```

with:

```
$('.auto-suggest-list li').css('background-color','#fff');
```

### [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/g3Fkb)

---

And you can also replace these two lines:

```
$('.auto-suggest-list li').css('background-color','#fff');
$('.auto-suggest-list li:nth-child(' + position + ')').css('background-color','#ddd');
```

with:

```
$('.auto-suggest-list li').css('background-color','#fff')
    .eq(position-1).css('background-color','#ddd');
```

### [jsFiddle with chaining here](http://jsfiddle.net/g3Fkb/1)

Comment: Well if I populate the ul with static HTML code, it's working fine. The problem seems to be occuring when used with PHP!